# Erro "Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found"

Tags: php, phpunit

Boa Noite, acabei de instalar o phpunit por um arquivo.phar e adicionando o path no windows mas quando vou executar os testes ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in C:\wamp64\www\QuebraLinha\test\CasoTeste.php on line 6
```

A Classe de testes que estou usando é essa:

```
<?php

require_once("../TextWrapExerciseInterface.class.php"); //Classe Interface fornecida pela Galoa
require_once("../QuebraLinha.class.php"); //Classe criada para implementar a classe Interface

class QuebraLinhaTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

  function test01(){  //Confirma se o retorno é um array
    $q = new QuebraLinha();
    $returnTest = array();
    $this->assertInternalType('array', $q->textWrap("Isso é um teste", 5));
  }

}

?>
```

Não estou usando nenhum autoloader no projeto. Desde ja agradeço

Comment: Como você está chamando o comando no cmd?

Comment: phpunit CasoTeste.php

Comment: Qual versão do phpunit você baixou? 6.3 stable ou 5.7?

Comment: versão 6.3 stable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O namespace "simulado" `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` é **"somente"** para a versão 5.7 do PHPunit

Na versão 6.3 do phpunit o namespace correto é `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` (o qual agora usa namespaces de verdade e não mais simulados).

Então seu código deve ficar assim:

```
<?php

require_once("../TextWrapExerciseInterface.class.php"); //Classe Interface fornecida pela Galoa
require_once("../QuebraLinha.class.php"); //Classe criada para implementar a classe Interface

class QuebraLinhaTest extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    public function test01()
    {
        $q = new QuebraLinha();
        $returnTest = array();
        $this->assertInternalType('array', $q->textWrap("Isso é um teste", 5));
    }
}
```

Comment: Funcionou muito obrigado